# How do I unhook an action? My current method does not seem to be working

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.
I am currently trying to remove the social sharing feature, which is displayed on the Product Pages.  I am trying to achieve this through the removal of the Action from its Hook, by placing the following code in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
?>
```

Said functions.php is placed within the Child Theme I have created.

Unfortunately, this is not removing the social sharing feature.  Does anyone know why?  To see if there was an issue with the Hooks, I added an Action to the same Hook, to which this worked.

Could it be possible that the Social Sharing feature has been placed in some parent folder which overrides/has higher priority over the functions.php file in the Child theme?  If this is the case, what would be my options in getting said feature removed.  I can only think of placing the affected file in the Child theme and then manually removing the relevant coding.  This is a last resort as it may cause problems, at a later date, when parent files are updated etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`woocommerce_template_single_sharing()` calls the Woocommerce template located at `woocommerce/templates/single-product/share.php` where there's a `do_action` call for other plugins & themes to add social sharing. If you want to "block" plugins from using that, your best bet (if you're building a theme) would be to use the built-in Woocommerce template override feature and simply prevent this `do_action` from firing. This would not cause any problems unless Woocommerce did a massive, structural rework. But otherwise, updating Woocommerce and any other plugins or a parent theme wouldn't affect your child theme.

In your child theme, create a directory called `woocommerce`, add a sub-directory called `single-product`, and then copy the `share.php` file from the above location in the plugin to that location in your theme.

Comment out the `do_action` and voila! No more social sharing and anything that hooks into that `do_action` won't run.

**As an alternative**...if you know exactly what's hooking into that `do_action`, you would run a `remove_action` on *that* bad boy, but then you need to hunt these things down and manually update your call any time a plugin tries to hook into it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  After playing around myself, the suggestion was pretty much what I did. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_actions

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function(){
   remove_all_actions('woocommerce_share_hook');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Whilst not my chosen approach this time,  this is something that may be useful in the future. :-)